# A query to find nearest distance trainers

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Name: course_trainer_combination

**Create Table Query:**

```
create table `course_trainer_combination` (
    `id` double ,
    `course` varchar (150),
    `trainer` varchar (150),
    `distance` float 
); 
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('1','Course A','Trainer A','110.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('2','Course A','Trainer B','105.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('3','Course A','Trainer C','115.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('4','Course B','Trainer A','112.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('5','Course B ','Trainer B','108.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('6','Course B','Trainer C','109.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('7','Course C','Trainer A','124.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('8','Course C','Trainer B','128.00');
insert into `course_trainer_combination` (`id`, `course`, `trainer`, `distance`) values('9','Course C','Trainer C','121.00');
```

My table is like

[image]

**Expected result:**

```
2 | Course A | Trainer B | 105
6 | Course B | Trainer C | 109
7 | Course C | Trainer A | 124
```

Comment: It seems fantastically unlikely that id would DOUBLE !?! Distance as FLOAT also seems a little odd - but not entirely unreasonable.

Comment: Why is the expected result 'expected'? And what have you tried already?

Comment: In other words, why '109'?

Comment: If you need minimum distance, then why for course -B it should be Trainer B, why trainer C

Comment: That's because Trainer B is teaching Course A and practically he cannot teach Course B on the same day let alone the same time. I am sorry I have not presented the complete scenario.

The basic thing is that I want to get the closest trainer to a course on the same day and same time. So if Trainer B is already teaching Course A on a day he cannot be assigned to Course B practically. So for Course B I have to look for another trainer who is nearest, hence Trainer C is assigned to Course B.

Hope this is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subquery

```
select ct.*
from course_trainer_combination ct
where ct.distance = (select min(ct1.distance) 
                     from course_trainer_combination ct1 
                     where ct1.course = ct.course 
                    );
```

If you are using newer version then you can use analytical function :

```
select ct.*
from (select ct.*, 
             rank() over (partition by ct.course order by ct.distance) as seq
      from course_trainer_combination ct
     ) ct
where ct.seq = 1;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am using MYSQL 5.7 so the analytical function will not work.

The first query is returning the entire table data.

Comment: @Techseria. . .  Used outer table `t` alias in subquery fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be like following.

```
select  id, 
        m.course, 
        trainer, 
        m.distance 
from   course_trainer_combination m 
       inner join (select course, 
                          Min(distance) distance
                   from   course_trainer_combination 
                   group by course)t 
               on t.course = m.course 
                  and t.distance = m.distance
```

**Note**: This will show two records if two trainer have same distance for 1 course.

Comment: **thanks for responding quickly. The result here would be as below:**

`2 | Course A | Trainer B | 105`
`5 | Course B | Trainer B | 109`
`7 | Course C | Trainer C | 121`

**My requirement is:**

`2 | Course A | Trainer B | 105`
`6 | Course B | Trainer C | 109`
`7 | Course C | Trainer A | 124`

`code`

Comment: You need to explain why 109 for second record and not 108?

Comment: That's because Trainer B is teaching Course A and practically he cannot teach Course B on the same day let alone the same time. I am sorry I have not presented the complete scenario. The basic thing is that I want to get the closest trainer to a course on the same day and same time. So if Trainer B is already teaching Course A on a day he cannot be assigned to Course B practically. So for Course B I have to look for another trainer who is nearest, hence Trainer C is assigned to Course B. Hope this is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by:

- **keeping track of the trainers** assigned to each course and
- selecting a row with the below conditions:

  - the **trainer** was not already assigned to a course
  - no other **row of the same course**, with a trainer not yet selected, **exists**

Use a [mysql user variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to keep track of the trainers already selected and use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to check weather the trainer has already assigned to a course:

```
SET @selectedTrainers :=''; 
SELECT *, @selectedTrainers := CONCAT(@selectedTrainers, ',', a.trainer) AS selectedTrainers
FROM `course_trainer_combination` a
where NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM `course_trainer_combination` b
      WHERE b.course = a.course
      AND a.distance > b.distance
      AND FIND_IN_SET(b.trainer, @selectedTrainers) = 0
      )
  AND FIND_IN_SET(a.trainer, @selectedTrainers) = 0
```